# Is create-react-app still good way to start a project in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Recently I've been trying to learn React and it's ecosystem. I've bought course on udemy [here](https://www.udemy.com/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/learn/v4/content). If someone have checked that please give me some feedback, I would be thankful.

Anyway. I am using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to follow the course. I believe there is someone here who can tell me if this is still good way to create such apps. I was searching down the internet, but didn't get good argumentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer your question ("Is it still a good way to start a project in react?"): yes! It provides a very solid and nice boilerplate in my opinion. It is however not always the best choice for the project you are planning. There is a good section about alternatives in the create-react-app User Guide (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#popular-alternatives).

Personally I like to use create-react-app with TypeScript (https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript).